# For staking pallet, what options do I have for ElectionProvider?

Tags: consensus, staking

I want to implement a simple PoS consensus mechanism where validator sets are chosen proportional to their stake. Do I need to write my own pallet implementing ElectionProviders trait or is there a ready-made solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it stands now, you have two implementations in substrate:

1. [`pallet-election-provider-multi-phase`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/index.html): This is a generic, asynchronous election pallet that can provide a wide range of elections to the staking pallet. This pallet is suitable for *any* election algorithm that is too heavy to compute onchain. It being too heavy or not is something that you need to answer based on your chain configuration. This pallet [needs an underlying `Solver`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.Solver). By default, substrate provides [multiple algorithms](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_election_provider_support/trait.NposSolver.html#implementors) here, but you can customize this to be anything you want.
2. [`SequentialPhragmen`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_election_provider_support/struct.SequentialPhragmen.html) is simply a struct that implements `ElectionProvider` by choosing the best validators based on the [Phragmen's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragmen%27s_voting_rules), and does the entire work on the fly. This type should only be used on networks that have small number of validators/nominators.

You can find a full list of implementations of `ElectionProvider` [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_election_provider_support/trait.ElectionProvider.html#implementors).

Note that both of these approaches are slightly sub-optimal if your election is too simple, as-in, there is no *election algorithm* involved. This is because substrate assumes the existence of an election algorithm from the point of view of `pallet-staking`, so instead of `pallet-staking` trying to keep track of top `x` validators on the fly, the entire nomination graph is  passed down to an `ElectionProvider` at some point for an election algorithm to compute it. Nonetheless, you are able to implement any

Answer (score 4):

Also, please note, that if you use the latest version of substrate, there are 2 newly introduced structs [`onchain::BoundedExecution`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6386eea9ecf33bd43e6ea319cfae27e18d32fdf3/frame/election-provider-support/src/onchain.rs#L62) , and [`onchain::UnboundedExecution`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6386eea9ecf33bd43e6ea319cfae27e18d32fdf3/frame/election-provider-support/src/onchain.rs#L69).

As its name implies, `UnboundedExecution` is not statically bounded, while `BoundedExecution` is. For on chain use, it's better to use `BoundedExecution` to make sure it does not go out of hand.

`UnboundedExecution` is generic over [`onchain::Config`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6386eea9ecf33bd43e6ea319cfae27e18d32fdf3/frame/election-provider-support/src/onchain.rs#L72) which can be used to configure the `Solver` and the `DataProvider`.

`BoundedExecution` is generic over [`onchain::BoundedConfig`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6386eea9ecf33bd43e6ea319cfae27e18d32fdf3/frame/election-provider-support/src/onchain.rs#L89) that offers the extra bounds to bound the execution.

You can see examples of their usage in the testing section or in the `pallet-election-provider-multi-phase`.

Please bear in mind that this is work in progress, and implementation may differ in the future, however this can be a handy wrapper to use for elections.