# Local network does not change validator set

Tags: substrate-node-template, staking, validator, pallet-staking

Currently, we have a local test net with 4 substrate nodes using [this runtime](https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/tree/dfo/gssmr-test-staking) which has the staking and session pallets. 2 nodes (Alice and Bob) are validators, placed in the chain spec json file and the other 2 (Charlie and Dave) were added as waiting validators while the chain was running with the goal to be chosen to the next session, but this never occurs. In each new epoch, the same validators (Alice and Bob) take place and I did not notice any session change event on polkadot JS UI. I would like to know if I'm missing some configuration or action to add new validators in a running network?

In the beginning of the first epoch I notice this event but I'm not sure if it is related to the session change
[image: election provider multi phase event]

The active validator set. It keeps the same as the through the epochs
[image: active validator set]

I've added two more validators using their respective session keys and I did not notice any validator set change (I've waited for more than 30 epochs)
[image: waiting validator set]

Edit: still not working after increasing the validator count (notice 3/4 validators, with 1 waiting)
[image: 3/4 validators, with 1 waiting]

Edit: adding event log
[image: events]

Comment: what value does `staking.ValidatorCount` has?

Comment: The validator count is equal to the number of initial validators, which in this case is 3 https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/blob/dfo/gssmr-test-staking/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L184 @kianenigma

Comment: And what is `type ElectionProvider` in staking? see: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/296/for-staking-pallet-what-options-do-i-have-for-electionprovider. You probably want to make sure you are using some of the simpler ones, running election onchain.

Comment: @kianenigma - `ElectionProvider` type is `ElectionProviderMultiPhase` https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/blob/dfo/gssmr-test-staking/runtime/src/lib.rs#L508

Comment: What are some of the events that you see from `ElectionProviderMultiPhase` pallet?

Comment: @kianenigma - I submitted an edit to show the events I'm seeing. It looks like there is one election round that happens, but then none after that (?)

Comment: Yeah that is strange. You should eventually get the `ElectionFinalized` event. Also, are you getting any events that signify the epoch/era has changed? Try `type Fallback = <whatever is GovernanaceFallback>` here: https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/blob/dfo/gssmr-test-staking/runtime/src/lib.rs#L435

Comment: I probably found *an* issue, not sure if it is the only one: Look into your validator logs: they must be trimming the solutions to nothing because you set the maximum possible weight/length for them to 0: https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/blob/ae6202b86fce3ca5f0f2a6c7913b73f30d65c2e1/runtime/src/lib.rs#L429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue have been solved in this PR- https://github.com/ChainSafe/substrate-node-template/pull/4

Answer (score 2):

You should rise the `validatorCount`, that sets a target for the ideal number of validators.

You can do that in different ways:

- [`set_validator_count`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L1208)
- [`increase_validator_count`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L1225)
- [`scale_validator_count`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L1242)

After that target is risen I would expect new validators being active.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alejandro! Unfortunately that is still not working...I have submitted an edit to Eclesio's original post that shows 3/4 active validators, with 1 waiting :/