# Offline validator is being picked in new era (in local chain)

Tags: validator, election

I am simulating how validators got switched when a validator is down in my localhost local chain setting.

I have 3-validator set in local chain genesis, Alice, Bob, and Charlie, but I only have Alice and Bob nodes up.

[image]

Blocks are produced and not finalized, this is expected. I then run a Dave node, and make it a waiting validator (shown below), and then called with sudo the extrinsic **staking** > **forceNewEraAlways()**.

[image]

With this setting, I would expect in the next epoch set in 2 mins, the network will drop the offlined Charlie (xCff2o...) and pick Dave as an active validator. *But I see that Charlie continue to be an active validator, not just in one era but all eras afterwards*.

In this case given I am the network admin with sudo key how can I force the validator sets to reelect and forcibly drop Charlie and add Dave in the validator set?

This is [the event log screenshot](https://tinyurl.com/2a8novn7) if it helps.

Thanks.

Related? [Local network does not change validator set](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/local-network-does-not-change-validator-set)

Answer (score 1):

Check if they are in [Invulnerables](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L236).